# Testing for Signup with already existing email is not working on the test database in django manage.py test command

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am having test case to test my signup API where it will respond back if the email is already taken, or it will return same email id if successfully created.

tests.py

```
class SignupTestCase(APITestCase):
    url = reverse('todos:signup')

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(self):
        self.random_num = random.randint(100, 999)
        self.username = f'Testing{self.random_num}'
        self.email = f'Testing{self.random_num}@gmail.com'
        self.password = f'Testing{self.random_num}'

    def test_signup_pass(self):
        payload = {
            'username': self.username,
            'email': self.email,
            'password': self.password,
        }
        response = self.client.post(self.url, payload)      
        res_data = json.loads(response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(res_data.get('email'), self.email)
        self.assertEqual(res_data.get('error'), None)

    def test_signup_fail(self):
        payload = {
            'username': self.username,
            'email': self.email,
            'password': self.password,
        }
        response = self.client.post(self.url, payload)      
        res_data = json.loads(response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(res_data.get('email'), None)
        self.assertEqual(res_data.get('error'), 'Email is taken')
```

In here, the second test, test_signup_fail has to pass because I am using same email which I have used in test_signup_pass, so it should raise IntegrityError in django signup method and should return an error message as 'Email is taken'.

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.db import IntegrityError

# Create your views here.
class signup(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
        username = data.get('username')
    
        user = User()
        user.email = email
        user.password = password
        user.username = username
    
        try:
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Email is taken'})

        return JsonResponse({'success': 'Successfully registered', 'email': user.email})
```

## Output

```
py manage.py test todos
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_signup_fail (todos.tests.SignupTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/g33k/Programming/django-learning/wordcount-project/todos/tests.py", line 42, in test_signup_fail
    self.assertEqual(res_data.get('email'), None)
AssertionError: 'Testing348@gmail.com' != None

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.010s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I have even checked the views with pdb,

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
> views.py(19)post()
-> try:
(Pdb) user
<User: Testing502>
(Pdb) n
> /views.py(20)post()
-> user.save()
(Pdb) n
> /views.py(24)post()
-> return JsonResponse({'success': 'Successfully registered', 'email': user.email})
(Pdb) c
F> /views.py(19)post()
-> try:
(Pdb) user
<User: Testing502>
(Pdb) n
> /views.py(20)post()
-> user.save()
(Pdb) n
> /views.py(24)post()
-> return JsonResponse({'success': 'Successfully registered', 'email': user.email})
(Pdb)
```

So, My question is it using different database on each test methods,

Comment: Your question (last sentence) seems incomplete.

Comment: My concern is why does user Testing502 as mentioned in the pdbs, is not giving me an email already exists error.